# D3 / change color of parent if child status is red or issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

This is the link for [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r3vtvs74/). This is not showing as on my code but what I have created is working fine on my end but not able to replicate on jsfiddle. What I want is if a child status is red or problem. the color of the parent should be red until we open it to the child having problem

like if "check 9" is having problem than "Test" should be red with text and node red when click on it it should come back to normal and the next that is check 1 should be red , if open than check 2 and so on until I reach the the problem child which is check 9 for demo.

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
        width = window.innerWidth - margin.right - margin.left - 20,
        height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom - 120;
    var i = 0,
        duration = 750,
        root;
    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
        .size([height, width]);

    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.5, 2]).on("zoom", function () {
         svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")}))
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    var flare = {
 "name": "Test",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "head 1",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "head 2",
     "children": [
      {
          "name": "head 3",
          "children": [
          { 
                "name": "head 4",
                "children": [
              { 
                    "name": "head 5",
                    "children": [
                  { 
                        "name": "head 6",
                        "children": [
                      { 
                            "name": "head 7",
                            "children": [
                          { 
                                "name": "head 8",
                                "children": [
                              { 
                                "name": "head 9",
                                "children": [
                                 {"name": "gi"},
                                 {"name": "hi"}
                             ]
                              }
                             ]
                          }
                         ]
                      }
                     ]
                  }
                 ]
              }
             ]    
          },
              { 
                "name": "head1",
                "children": [
              { 
                    "name": "head 2",
                    "children": [
                  { 
                        "name": "head 3",
                        "children": [
                      { 
                            "name": "head 4",
                            "children": [
                          { 
                                "name": "head 5",
                                "children": [
                              { 
                                "name": "head 6",
                                "children": [
                                 {"name": "hi"},
                                 {"name": "hi"}
                             ]
                              }
                             ]
                          }
                         ]
                      }
                     ]
                  }
                 ]
              }
             ]    
          },
              { 
                "name": "head 1",
                "children": [
              { 
                    "name": "head 2",
                    "children": [
                  { 
                        "name": "head 3",
                        "children": [
                      { 
                            "name": "head 4",
                            "children": [
                          { 
                                "name": "head 5",
                                "children": [
                              { 
                                "name": "head 6",
                                "children": [
                                 {"name": "hi"},
                                 {"name": "hi"}
                             ]
                              },
                                    {   
                                "name": "R",
                                "children": [
                                 {"name": "hi"},
                                 {"name": "hi"}
                             ]
                              },
                                    {   
                                "name": "rr",
                                "children": [
                                 {"name": "hi"},
                                 {"name": "hi"}
                             ]
                              }
                             ]
                          }
                         ]
                      }
                     ]
                  }
                 ]
              }
             ]    
          }
         ]
      }
     ]    
      }
     ]
    },
       {
   "name": "check 1",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "check 2",
            "status":"red",
     "children": [
      {
          "name": "check 3",
          "children": [
          { 
                "name": "check 4",
                "children": [
              { 
                    "name": "check 5",
                    "children": [
                  { 
                        "name": "check 6",
                        "children": [
                      { 
                            "name": "check 7",
                            "children": [
                          { 
                                "name": "check 8",
                                "children": [
                              { 
                                "name": "check 9",
                "status":"red",
                                "children": [
                                    {"name": "problem","url":"www.google.com"},
                                    {"name": "hi","url":"www.google.com"}
                             ]
                              }
                             ]
                          }
                         ]
                      }
                     ]
                  }
                 ]
              }
             ]    
          }
         ]
      }
     ]    
      }
     ]
    }
    ]
    };
      //if (error) throw error;

      root = flare;
      root.x0 = height / 2;
      root.y0 = 0;

      function collapse(d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d._children.forEach(collapse);
          d.children = null;
        }
      }

      root.children.forEach(collapse);
      update(root);

    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

    function update(source) {

      // Compute the new tree layout.
      var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
          links = tree.links(nodes);

      // Normalize for fixed-depth.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

      // Update the nodes…
      var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
          .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

      // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
      var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
          .on('contextmenu',d3.contextMenu(content))
          .on("click", click);

      nodeEnter.append("circle")
          .attr("r", 1e-6)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? (d.status ? d.status : "#f77a03") : "#fff"; });//changed

      nodeEnter.append("text")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
          .attr("dy", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
          .style('fill',function(d) { return d.status ? d.status : "white"; })//added
          .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
          .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

      // Transition nodes to their new position.
      var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

      nodeUpdate.select("circle")
          .attr("r", 4.5)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? (d.status ? d.status : "#f77a03") : "#fff"; });//changed

      nodeUpdate.select("text")
          .style('fill',function(d) { return d.status ? d.status : "black"; })//added
          .style("fill-opacity", 1);

      // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
      var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
          .remove();

      nodeExit.select("circle")
          .attr("r", 1e-6);

      nodeExit.select("text")
          .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

      // Update the links…
      var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
          .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

      // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
      link.enter().insert("path", "g")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
          });

      // Transition links to their new position.
      link.transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("d", diagonal);

      // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
      link.exit().transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
          })
          .remove();

      // Stash the old positions for transition.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
      });
    }
    //expand and collapse
    function expand(d){   
        var children = (d.children)?d.children:d._children;
        if (d._children) {        
            d.children = d._children;
            d._children = null;       
        }
        if(children)
          children.forEach(expand);
    }

    function expandAll(){
        expand(root); 
        update(root);
    }

    function collapseAll(){
        root.children.forEach(collapse);
        collapse(root);
        update(root);
    }
    // Toggle children on click.
    function click(d) {
      if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
      update(d);
    }
    //on right click
    var content = [
                {
                    title: 'Item #1',
                    action: function(elm, d, i) {
                        window.open(d.url, '_blank');
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: 'Item #2',
                    action: function(elm, d, i) {
                        window.open(d.url, '_blank');
                    }
                }
            ]
```

Don't want node to change it's location

Suppose this is a part of json, node "check 9" is having status "red". But when we load the page we can't see it until we expand all or reach that point, So what I want is to make the color of root node red when the page loads so I will know that the there is somewhere some problem(some node having status red). then when I will click on root node or the furtherest child node visible, in this case "Check 2" will be red on page load and when I click on it, as it has no status of it's own, it will change to default color and "check 3" will change to red and so on until it reach "check 9" which will remain red as it status is red. This is to be done only in case of status is red not in any other case. If still not clear than I really need to join sentence forming classes :(

```
"name": "check 1",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "check 2",
     "children": [
      {
          "name": "check 3",
          "children": [
          {
                "name": "check 9",
                "status":"red",
                "children": [
                 {"name": "problem","url":"www.google.com"},
                 {"name": "hi","url":"www.google.com"}
                             ]
                              }
                             ]
                          }
                         ]
                      }
                     ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I havent tested this properly as you havent got a status on the children, but something like this will work :

```
nodeEnter.append("circle")
.attr("r", 1e-6)
.style("fill", function(d) {
    console.log('children')
    console.log(d.children)
    if (d.children && d.children.length > 0) {
      var isRed = false;
      for (i = 0; i < d.children.length; i++) {
        if (d.children[i].status == 'red' || d.children[i].status == 'problem') {
          isRed = true; //set to true if any are 'red' or 'problem'
          return 'red'
        }
      }
      if (isRed == false) { //check if any are 'red' or 'problem'
        return 'green' //if not, colour green
      }

    }
  } else {
    return 'white'; //no children
  }
  //return d._children ? (d.status ? d.status : "#f77a03") : "#fff";
}); //changed
```

Basically in the 'fill' for that node, if it has children, go through each child if any one of them has a status of 'red' or 'problem' return red, otherwise turn green, if it has no children colour white :)

Your code in a fiddle so you can see it yourself : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/r3vtvs74/4/

Comment: Also the second part of your question is hard to understand, could you elaborate ?

Comment: think `d.children[i].status = 'red' ` should have been `d.children[i].status == 'red'` right?

Comment: @Cyril good spot, as mentioned it's not testing, thanks for that, answer is edited:)

Comment: One more thing is, for loop will always run once...i think the algo needs a change.

Comment: @Cyril attentive today :) Edited :)

Comment: Sorry, edited the link, should work fine now. I'm not sure what you want, it doesnt make sense :/